# How to retrieve entities without their entities associated?

Tags: orm, doctrine, symfony

My code is

```
 $bars = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Bar')->findAll();
```

And the Entity

```
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="location", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
 */
private $location;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="zipcode", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
 */
private $zipcode;


/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
 */

private $description;

/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Waiter", mappedBy="bar", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
*/ 
protected $waiters;

/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Table_", mappedBy="bar", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
*/ 
protected $tables;

/** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Stock_food", mappedBy="bar", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY") */

private $stockfoods;

/** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Stock_drink", mappedBy="bar", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY") */

private $stockdrinks;
```

I want retrieve only the bars entity without their entities associated (Waiter, Table_, Stock_drink, Stock_food).

The response is all data but I only need name, location, zipcode and descriptión.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: The simpliest solution is add a custom method in your repository and write the query without using the ORM shortcut like findOneBy, findAll, etc.

Comment: I'd like to use the ORM because i need work with objects not with queries in DQL

Comment: Are You sure, that You get full objects? IMO You only get Proxy classes (which will be created).
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html
EXTRA_LAZY don't make JOINS - instead if You try to get a property from such object Doctrine will make additional SQL query

Comment: To clarify, also if you write a custom query you can retrieve objects. It's  simple retrieve only the needed data/object. Take the time to read more in-deep the docs.

Comment: Although in all associated entities i've put fetch extra lazy, when i do a query, it returns all the entities associated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Helloo

I found the solution!! I'm using raw SQL queries, DBAL

```
    $conn = $em->getConnection();
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM Bar';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $bars = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Thankss!!